# How to convert the expression iloc from pandas to Pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

How to convert the pandas expression to pyspark , which it seems not working ,then convert the dataframe to an array  ?

```py
+---- +------+-----+
|idx  |Type1 |Type2| 
+---- +------+-----+
|1    |   D  | C   |
|2    |  5.0 | null| 
|3    |  6.0 | 7.0 |     
+-----+------+-----+
N=2
df = df.iloc[-N:, :] #expression in pandas

df = df.collect()[-N:][:] # expression in Pyspark
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming column `idx` is unique incremental, you can use :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.filter(F.col("idx") > (df.count() - N))
```

Or

```
df = df.orderBy(F.desc("idx")).limit(N)
```

Or

```
max_idx = df.agg(F.max("idx").alias("idx")).first().idx

df = df.filter(F.col("idx") > (max_idx - N))
```